# Style of axis tick labels in d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

The following script creates a point scale axis with three labels and a title. The body css selector defines the font-family and font-size of all text elements in the body. While the axis title is influenced by the css rules, the axis tick labels are not, although they are themselves text elements. I know I can set the tick label style using the .axis text selector. Maybe I am missing something obvious here, but what prevents the tick labels from being rendered with the body selector?

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="d3.min.V4.js"></script>

<style>

body {
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size: 18px;
}

</style>

<body>

</body>

<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 40, left: 70},
    width = 600,
    height = 100;

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                       .attr('width', width)
                       .attr('height', height);

var xScale = d3.scalePoint().domain(["blue", "red", "green"]).range([margin.left, width-margin.right]);

// Add the x Axis
 svg.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
     .attr("class", "axis")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
     );

//x axis title
svg.append('text')
   .text('Colors')
   .attr('x', width/2)
   .attr('y', height - 5)
   .style("text-anchor", "middle");


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis), the axis generator automatically sets the font-size and the font-family of the ticks in the container `g` element, this being the default style (code copied from the API's example):

```
//styles applied to the outer g element:
<g fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle">
    <path class="domain" stroke="#000" d="M0.5,6V0.5H880.5V6"></path>
    <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <line stroke="#000" y2="6" x1="0.5" x2="0.5"></line>
        <text fill="#000" y="9" x="0.5" dy="0.71em">0.0</text>
    </g>
    //etc...
</g>
```

Thus, it seems that due to the specificity and precedence rules, this style prevails over your `body` CSS style.

To change the ticks, you'll have to specify `text` in your CSS (or using a class or an ID).

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't address my question. The axis title 'Colors' is also an SVG text but it is influenced by the body CSS selector.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. It's always good practice to go through the source code!

Answer (score 3):

As Gerardo mentioned, the API will draw with fill #000 as default.
A work around would be to re-select the text and re-style it.
Which looks something like this:

```
var xScale = d3.scalePoint().domain(["blue", "red", "green"]).range([margin.left, width-margin.right]);

// Add the x Axis
var xTicks = svg.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
     .attr("class", "axis")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
     );

xTicks.selectAll('text').attr('fill', function(d){
    return d;
  });
```